# Method invocation produces NPE - Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to set the weather on NavHeader in my app when the floating action button is clicked.

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {

        WeatherAPI.Factory.getInstance().getWeather().enqueue(new Callback<Weather>() {
          @Override public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {

            Query query = response.body().getQuery();
            degree.setText(query.getResults().getChannel().getItem().getCondition().getTemp());
          }

          @Override public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e("failure", t.getMessage());
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

However I get NPE when I click the button.

```
public interface WeatherAPI {

  String BASE_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/";

  @GET("PATH CONTINUES HERE")
  Call<Weather> getWeather();

  class Factory {

    private static WeatherAPI service;

    public static WeatherAPI getInstance() {

      if (service == null) {

        Retrofit retrofit =
            new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();

        retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);

        return service;
      } else {
        return service;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It warns that getQuery() invocation may produces NullPointerException.

Here is my Query class:

```
public class Query {

    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private int count;
    @SerializedName("created")
    @Expose
    private String created;
    @SerializedName("lang")
    @Expose
    private String lang;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private Results results;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public Results getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

}
```

here is the error:

> 05-19 09:46:22.399 26168-26168/us.egek.rockclimbingkaynaklar
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: us.egek.rockclimbingkaynaklar, PID: 26168
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{us.egek.rockclimbingkaynaklar/us.egek.rockclimbingkaynaklar.Activities.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   us.egek.rockclimbingkaynaklar.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)

Comment: I can see that your service object is never initialised in the code. So `WeatherAPI.Factory.getInstance()` will always give `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `WeatherAPI.Factory.getInstance()` method, you should assign the service property to the retrofit create statement

```
service = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);
```